# Add Category taxonomy for custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I made a custom post type 'games', already added 'categories' taxonomy when initializing. I can add categories / tags for a given entry, but custom posts **do not show up in category / tag lists**. I did not add any custom template file (yet).

```
function register_games()
{
    register_post_type('games', array
    (
        'label'               => __('games', 'twentytwelve'),
        'description'         => __('Best iOS / Android games', 'twentytwelve'),

        // UI.
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-tablet',
        'labels'              => array
        (
            'name'                => _x('Games', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentytwelve'),
            'singular_name'       => _x('Game', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentytwelve'),
            'menu_name'           => __('Games', 'twentytwelve'),
            'parent_item_colon'   => __('Parent Game', 'twentytwelve'),
            'all_items'           => __('All Games', 'twentytwelve'),
            'view_item'           => __('View Game', 'twentytwelve'),
            'add_new_item'        => __('Add New Game', 'twentytwelve'),
            'add_new'             => __('Add New', 'twentytwelve'),
            'edit_item'           => __('Edit Game', 'twentytwelve'),
            'update_item'         => __('Update Game', 'twentytwelve'),
            'search_items'        => __('Search Game', 'twentytwelve'),
            'not_found'           => __('Not Found', 'twentytwelve'),
            'not_found_in_trash'  => __('Not found in Trash', 'twentytwelve'),
        ),

        // Features.
        'supports'            => array
        (
            'title',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'trackbacks',
            'custom-fields',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
        ),

        // Attributes.
        'public'              => true,
        'taxonomies'          => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'has_archive'         => true,

        // Admin.
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_games_metaboxes'

    ));
}
```

Excerpts show up in `<DOMAIN>/index.php/games/`, but not in `<DOMAIN>/index.php/category/games/` (I created and added such category).

Comment: May be [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29857/can-not-search-my-custom-post-type) thread will help you.

Comment: True, thanks. I had to squeeze it into search results, now works fine.